# How to convert alphabet to binary?

Tags: binary

How to convert alphabet to binary? I search on Google and it says that first convert alphabet to its ASCII numeric value and than convert the numeric value to binary. Is there any other way to convert ?
And if that's the only way than is the binary value of "A" and 65 are same?

```
BECAUSE ASCII vale of 'A'=65 and when converted to binary its 01000001
AND 65 =01000001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed the way which text is converted to binary.

And to answer your second question, yes it is true that the binary value of A and 65 are the same. If you are wondering how CPU distinguishes between  "A" and "65" in that case, you should know that ***it doesn't***. It is up to your operating system and program to distinguish how to treat the data at hand. For instance, say your memory looked like the following starting at 0 on the left and incrementing right:

```
00000001 00001111 000000001 01100110
```

This binary data could mean anything, and only has a meaning in the context of whatever program it is in. In a given program, you could have it be read as: 
 

1. An integer, in which case you'll get one number. 
2. Character data, in which case you'll output 4 ASCII characters.

In short, binary is read by CPUs, which do not understand the context of anything and simply execute whatever they are given. It is up to your program/OS to specify instructions in order for data to be handled properly.

Thus, converting the alphabet to binary is dependent on the program in which you are doing so, and outside the context of a program/OS converting the alphabet to binary is really the exact same thing as converting a sequence of numbers to binary, as far as a CPU is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Number 65 in decimal is 0100 0001 in binary and it refers to letter A in binary alphabet table (ASCII) https://www.bin-dec-hex.com/binary-alphabet-the-alphabet-letters-in-binary. The easiest way to convert alphabet to binary is to use some online converter or you can do it manually with binary alphabet table.